# Alice, Bob, and their 100 potential friends.

Tags: probability, independence

The question is also stated here:

[$A$: set of Alice's frieds, $B$: Bob's friends, $C$: all people. Find $P(A \subseteq B)$ and $P(A \cup B = C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061230/a-set-of-alices-frieds-b-bobs-friends-c-all-people-find-pa-subs)

> Alice, Bob, and 100 other people live in a small town. Let $C$ be the
> set consisting of the 100 other people, let $A$ be the set of people
> in $C$ who are friends with Alice, and let $B$ be the set of people in
> $C$ who are friends with Bob. Suppose that for each person in C, Alice
> is friends with that person with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, and
> likewise for Bob, with all of these friendship statuses independent.
>
> (c) Find $P (A\cup B = C)$.

I was wondering if anyone could help point out where my logic is wrong with a Principal of Inclusion/Exclusion argument. The solution seems to be incorrect, but I can't quite figure out where it went wrong.

My solution:

$P(A \cup B = C)$ can be thought as one minus the probability that any of the people in $C$ are not befriended.

Let $P_i$ be neither $A$ nor $B$ befriended person $i$.

$ P(A \cup B = C) = 1 - P(P_1 \cup P_2 \cup ... \cup P_{100})$

Now we can use the principal of inclusion and exclusion:

$1 - \sum_{i=1}^{100} (-1)^{i + 1}{100 \choose i}(\frac{1}{2})^{2i} = 3.85(10^{-8})$

The solution proposed is $(\frac{3}{4}) ^ {100} = 3.21(10^{-13})$ by the logic that for each person, the probability they are selected by either Bob or Alice is $1 - $ the probability they are selected by neither $\rightarrow P(P_i) = 1 - (\frac{1}{2})^2 = \frac{3}{4}$.

Essentially the solution uses the idea that each person is independent to say $P(A + B = C)$ is the probability that person 1, ..., person 100 are a friend of either Bob or Alice, and then we can multiply the probability each because they are independent.

I understand this is simpler and cleaner than my solution, but why is my solution inaccurate.

Comment: You must have an arithmetic mistake.  Your analysis is correct but [your sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1+%2B+%28sum+from+i%3D1+to+100+of+%28%28-1%29%5Ei+*+%28100+choose+i%29+*+%281%2F2%29%5E%282i%29%29%29) should also have been $\approx 3.21\times 10^{-13}$.  [Comparing the values](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%283%2F4%29%5E100+-+%281+%2B+%28sum+from+i%3D1+to+100+of+%28%28-1%29%5Ei+*+%28100+choose+i%29+*+%281%2F2%29%5E%282i%29%29%29%29) the two answers are indeed equal.